# What link will return an address when I pass latitude and longitude?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=address&output=csv

The above link gives the latitude and longitude from address.

I want a similar link to get address from latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the `latitude` and `longitude` in the query string.  So something like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=43.6426038,-79.3871169&output=csv

will return

`200,9,"CN Tower, Toronto, ON M5V 2T6, Canada"`

Full description of Google Maps Parameters here: http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

Using 
Below Api you can Get Address From Lat And Log
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ws.geonames.org/findNearestAddress?lat=%f&lng=%f", newLocation.lattitude, newLocation.longitude]; NSURL *url = [NSURL URLFromString:address];